# How to create/delete share access policy in azure blob storage using java?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

How i can create or delete share access policy using java api.

Unable to get any official documentation for creating access policy using java SDK.

below is the azure blob dependency i am using in my procject

```
Gradle dependency: compile group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-storage-blob', version: '12.8.0'
```

i found some example but looks like it won't belong to the azure-storage-blob dependency that i am using.
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.SharedAccessBlobPolicy

is there any api in JAVA SDK for creating / deleting shared access policy for blob storage

[image]

Comment: Hi Mohit, if my post is helpful, please mark it as an answer. If you mark answers timely, others will be more willing to answer your queries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClientBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobAccessPolicy;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobSignedIdentifier;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.PublicAccessType;

public class App {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String connstr = "<storage account conn str>";
                String containerName = "<container name>";

                BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder().connectionString(connstr)
                                .containerName(containerName).buildClient();

                BlobSignedIdentifier identifier = new BlobSignedIdentifier().setId("test policy")
                                .setAccessPolicy(new BlobAccessPolicy().setStartsOn(OffsetDateTime.now())
                                                .setExpiresOn(OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(7))
                                                .setPermissions("cd")); //permission for create and delete

                ArrayList<BlobSignedIdentifier> identifiers = new ArrayList<BlobSignedIdentifier>();
                identifiers.add(identifier);
                blobContainerClient.setAccessPolicy(PublicAccessType.CONTAINER, identifiers);
        }       
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: it will not create shared access policy right?

it will create shared access signature (SAS) i want to created access policy that i can edit /delete

Comment: @MohitSingh,hi, it is helpful ?

Comment: can i delete (test policy) access policy also ?

i can see code help to create access policy but how we can delete it also

Comment: @MohitSingh, could you please open a new case and let me know its link? Once I see it, I'll research for you immediately : )